# GausianNB: Could not convert string to float: 'Thu Apr 16 23:58:58 2015'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, gaussian, data-science

I'm trying to solve a machine learning problem using GaussianNB. I've certain fields which are not in proper date format, so I converted them into UNIX format. For example column `state_changed_at` has value in csv as `1449619185`. I'm converting it into proper date format.

When I'm selecting those date features to train my model, I get this error:

> Could not convert string to float: 'Thu Apr 16 23:58:58 2015'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import time
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

train = pd.read_csv("datasets/train2.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("datasets/test.csv")
train.head()

import time

#   state_changed_at,deadline,created_at,launched_at are date time fields
# and I'm converting it into unix format
unix_cols = ['deadline','state_changed_at','launched_at','created_at']

for x in unix_cols:
    train[x] = train[x].apply(lambda k: time.ctime(k))
    test[x] = test[x].apply(lambda k: time.ctime(k))


#   state_changed_at,deadline,created_at,launched_at are date time fields.
cols_to_use = ['keywords_len' ,'keywords_count','state_changed_at','deadline','created_at','launched_at']

target = train['final_status']

# data for modeling
k_train = train[cols_to_use]
k_test = test[cols_to_use]


gnb = GaussianNB()

model = MultinomialNB()
model.fit(k_train, target)  # this lines gives me error saying: could not convert string to float: 'Thu Apr 16 23:58:58 2015'

expected = target
predicted = model.predict(k_test)
print(model.score(k_test, predicted, sample_weight=None))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your confusion?  You gave it DateTime columns.  [SKLearn.fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit.html) doesn't accept that type.  Specifically:

```
Parameters: 
X : array-like, dtype=float64, size=[n_samples, n_features]
Y : array, dtype=float64, size=[n_samples]
```

If you want to train on times, you need to cast (or leave) them as an ingestible type, i.e. basic numeric.  Can you leave them in their original, epoch-based integer form while you perform the fitting?

Comment: Ok. So am I supposed to use datetime fields without converting to UTX format?

Comment: No.  Once you convert to DateTime, you've lost.  DateTime does not have a built-in conversion to `float64`, which is the base type.  You need to keep it as a numeric value, such as the original `1449619185`.  If you need to display DateTime values, either convert *after* you apply libSVM, or make an extra column for each DateTime item.

Comment: Will my model give good precision if we used float directly without converting it.?

Comment: I have no idea ... what happened when you tried it?  Don't ask *me* when you have the ultimate authority in your computer.  :-)  You'll get the same precision you'd get with converted data.  DateTime doesn't extract any new information, nor does it change the relationships among the values.

Comment: Ok. I had tried and precision got low that's why I asked. Anyways thanks for clearing my doubt.